# Make rows from Parent table go down automatically to child table

Tags: sql, database, parent, categories

I have 3 tables. One table `EMPLOYEE` which is a parent table, it has all the employees in the company, then I have child tables which have `EMP_ID` as PK and FK from the `EMPLOYEE` table and other specific information. Considering that the `EMPLOYEE` table has `EMP_TYPE` which carries the type of the employee, is it possible by entering a record into the `EMPLOYEE`, the record should automatically recognize its type and copy itself to the relevant table?

Comment: Hmmm... I may not be understanding this question correctly, but if you have to copy values to child tables it sounds like you have a certain amount of redundancy in your structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [trigger function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) for that, which checks the `EMP_TYPE` and then inserts data in the corresponding child table. Make sure that these triggers are fired when you insert data into your parent table.

Or you look for a [object-relational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_database) database.

For MySQL it could look like this (without knowing the real structure of your model, but it should be easily adapted to your specific case):

```
CREATE TRIGGER testref AFTER INSERT ON Employee
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.EMP_TYPE = 'PROGRAMMER' THEN
      INSERT INTO Programmer (id, type, name, salary, start_date) values (NEW.EMP_ID, NEW.EMP_TYPE, NEW.NAME, NEW.SALARY, NEW.START_DATE);
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO Intern (id, type, name, salary) values (NEW.EMP_ID, NEW.EMP_TYPE, NEW.NAME, NEW.SALARY);
    END IF;
```

END;

Comment: i was hoping for an easier way...but i guess my fate is triggers.

Comment: can you help me write such a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this:

1. Using an on-insert database trigger.
2. Do it from the front end or business layer (I am assuming you have that)

Comment: If you need help with triggers you will have to specify what dbms are you using (oracle, MySQL, etc)